# Assigning the same task to multiple users with a specific completion

Tags: workflow, user

I am using SP Designer. I need to assign the same task to 2 people at the same time and if one of them completes the task, it must be enough in order to go to next step in workflow. How can I accomplish it ?

Thanks for your kind attentions.